# How to binding "Location.X" with a variable?

Tags: c#, data-binding, location

I want to bindings my forms "Location" property to two separated variables.

But the below code can not compile success.

Can anyone give my a hint?

```
DataBindings.Add("Location.X", _settings, "FormLocationX", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
DataBindings.Add("Location.Y", _settings, "FormLocationY", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Comment: What error you are getting while compilation_?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya It throw System.ArgumentException => Can not binding to  'Location.X'.